# fill a buffer successively

Tags: c, string, pointers, char, printf

i intend to fill a char-pointer array successively in a for-loop. the content to fill in is a integer so i need to cast. but i didn't get the result i want to..

```
for (i=0;i<max0;i++){
    sprintf(buf, "%d", content[i]);
}
```

sprintf replaces the hole buf, but i want to append.

```
for (i=0;i<max0;i++){
   buf[i]=(char) contint[i]
}
```

but this isn't working too. it seems to me, i get ascii-code of the content[i].

Comment: You can't convert a number to a char like that with the expected output. The integer can be -2,147,483,648, 2,147,483,647 or anything in between (assuming 32 bit here). A char only fits 0 - 255 (-128 - 127).

Comment: the value triggers 0 / 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it using snsprintf

```
for (i=0;i<max0;i++){
   length += snprintf(buf+length, buflen-length, "%d", content[i]);
}
```

thanks for your answers!!

Comment: The second argument of snprintf is unsigned (size_t), it means that if length > buflen, then buflen-length will underflow and snprintf will happily write outside of the buffer creating a buffer overflow. Note that the return of snprintf is equal to the number of bytes which would have been written if enough space had been available and NOT the number of bytes really written.

Answer (score 2):

[sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/) returns the number of char written. You can make use of this in appending the integers to the buffer.

Something like:

```
int pos = 0;
for (i=0;i<max0;i++){
   pos += sprintf(buf+pos, "%d", content[i]);
}
```

Comment: yeah, i'll try snprintf. thanks :D.. sometimes the first idea is the best one. damn it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using pointer arithmetic:

```
char *p = buf;
for (i=0;i<max;i++)
{
      int num_written = sprintf(p, "%d", content[i]);
      if(num_written == -1)
      { 
       //error handling 
       break;
      }

      p += num_written;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
for (i=0; i<max0; ++i){
  sprintf(buf, "%d", content[i]);
  strcat(resultbuf, buf);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it might sound silly, but i tweaked your code something like this:-

```
for (i=0;i<max0;i++){ 
   buf[i]=(char) (48+ contint[i]);
}
```

// here 48 is ascii code of 0